# How to setup phpmyadmin with nginx and access it from http://vps-ip/phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx

The phpmyadmin files are located here `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`

And I have this server block code that allows me to access phpmyadmin only from `http://vps-ip/`:

```
server {
        listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name ein;

        location / {
                root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
                index index index.php;
                try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?q=$uri&amp&$args;
                port_in_redirect off;
        }

        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max;
                root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                fastcgi_pass php;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 360;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 360;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }

        location ~ /.htaccess { deny all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location ~ /.htpasswd { deny all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /favicon.ico { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
}
```

What changes I need to do in order to access phpmyadmin from `http://vps-ip/phpmyadmin` and access my website from `http://vps-ip/` ?

**OK I found the solution for this:**

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ { 
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/; 

    location ~ \.php$ { 
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; 
    fastcgi_pass php; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The act of doing this is called Aliasing, basically setting something to go to somewhere else. I personally don't have experience with NGINX but According to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/223028/alias-using-nginx-causing-phpmyadmin-login-endless-loop), you should be using:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
}
```

Hopefully this helps. :)

Comment: I added this location, now when I go to http://my-ip/phpmyadmin I get "No input file specified."

Comment: OK I copied exactly the same code from the question that you linked and that fixed my problem. So here's the solution again http://serverfault.com/questions/223028/alias-using-nginx-causing-phpmyadmin-login-endless-loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your root.  Right now you have it as `root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/`.  This means nginx thinks `http://vps-ip/` should be served from `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`.  Are the files you want to share at `http://vps-ip/` located in `/usr/share/`? (That seems like a really odd place for them, you should probably make a folder for your website).